# Twig digit instead of text

Tags: twig

I have items in the taxesAmountData array,

```
array: 4 [
"netAmount" => 1000.0
"taxRate" => "zw"
"taxAmount" => 0.0
"grossAmount" => 1000.0
]

array: 4 [
"netAmount" => 1000.0
"taxRate" => 0
"taxAmount" => 0.0
"grossAmount" => 1000.0
]
```

when I want to display values in a loop, I get a strange error, ie instead of "zw" I get 0. What's worse if I do:

```
{% for taxAmountsData in taxesAmountData}
{% if taxAmountsData.taxRate == 'zw'}
         i have zw
{% elseif taxAmountsData.taxRate == 0}
         i have 0
{% endif%}
{% endfor%}
```

it shows me 2x i have 0, and treats it as another 0

Comment: Are u sure nothing is tranforming the data before passing it to `twig`? As seen [here](https://twigfiddle.com/gfoypf) it should work. Do note that `"zw" == 0` is `true` in a `PHP` environment because it is loosely typed (meaning that `zw` will be casted to an integer before comparison)

Comment: Try using `{{ dump(taxesAmountData ) }}` to verify the data inside `twig`. Do note this requires you to load the debug extension from `twig`

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if its a copy-paste mistake, but you are missing closing `%` on your tags:

Try:

```
{% for taxAmountsData in taxesAmountData %}
    {% if taxAmountsData.taxRate == 'zw' %}
        i have zw
    {% elseif taxAmountsData.taxRate == 0 %}
        i have 0
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```